# Sending GET request for an IP address

Tags: python

I need to send a request to a web server of mine to start a stream. The web server is located at `0.0.0.0` (of course I can change the address).

How can I send a "GET" request to that server?

I already tried using `httplib` or `urllib2` or `3` and they seem not to work with IP address.

> I know that a local DNS server will map the address to a url, but that is not the goal to set up the server every time I want to execute the code in a new network.

Thank a lot.

Comment: Is the ip address reachable by other means, perhaps from a browser?

Comment: Can you provide code so we can see what's not working for you?

Comment: Try with requests

Comment: requests.get('http://0.0.0.0/')

Comment: John Gordon, yes the IP is reachable from the browser for pinging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `requests`:
`requests.get('http://0.0.0.0')`

or even better

```
s = requests.Session()

s.get('http://0.0.0.0')
r = s.get('https://httpbin.org/cookies')
```

to keep the connection persistent, which is probably more like what you want.
See more about `requests` sessions at http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/

Or you could just convert the IP address to a hostname using
`socket.gethostbyaddr(ip)` with urllib
to convert the IP address to a host name

Comment: Also can use `from urllib.request import urlopen` `url = "url"` `response = urlopen(url)`

Comment: thanks for your respond. This code works good, the only problem is that now I am not able to see the stream on the client side, however I can see the server gets the request and starts the stream.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because you probably haven't included the web protocol to use (i.e. HTTP or HTTPS). Try it like this

```
import urllib2
urllib2.urlopen('http://0.0.0.0')
```